# Calculating size (in bytes) of an image in memory

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am writing a small app in Swift to resize an image. I would like to calculate the size of the resized image (in bytes/KB). How do I do that?

Here is the piece of code I am working on:

```
var assetRepresentation :  ALAssetRepresentation = asset.defaultRepresentation()

self.originalImageSize = assetRepresentation.size()

selectedImageSize = self.originalImageSize

// now scale the image
let image = selectedImage
let hasAlpha = false
let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sizeChange, !hasAlpha, scale)
image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: sizeChange))

let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

self.backgroundImage.image = scaledImage
```

Since scaledImage is not yet saved, how do I go about calculating its size?

Comment: Bitmap size? Or size it would be on disk in a particular format?

Comment: size it would be on disk after saving or sharing. (the image is not saved yet, I want to display its size on the screen before it is saved.)

Comment: Use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation` and get the size of the resulting `NSData`.

Answer (score 8):

Since you're looking to display the size of the file to your user, [NSByteCountFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSByteCountFormatter_Class/index.html) is a good solution. It takes NSData, and can output a String representing the size of the data in a human readable format (like 1 KB, 2 MB, etc).

Since you're dealing with a UIImage though, you'll have to convert the UIImage to NSData to use this, which for example, can be done using `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()`, which returns NSData representative of the image in the specified format. A usage example could look something like this:

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(scaledImage)
let formatted = NSByteCountFormatter.stringFromByteCount(
    Int64(data.length),
    countStyle: NSByteCountFormatterCountStyle.File
)

println(formatted)
```

**Edit**: If as suggested by your title, you're looking to show this information with a specific unit of measurement (bytes), this can also be achieved with NSByteCountFormatter. You just have to create an instance of the class and set its `allowedUnits` property.

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(scaledImage)
let formatter = NSByteCountFormatter()

formatter.allowedUnits = NSByteCountFormatterUnits.UseBytes
formatter.countStyle = NSByteCountFormatterCountStyle.File

let formatted = formatter.stringFromByteCount(Int64(data.length))

println(formatted)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this to create my image:

```
var imageBuffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = nil
let ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageBuffer, UInt(width), UInt(height), UInt(8), bitmapBytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)
```

imageBuffer is allocated automatically (see according documentation).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am looking for size on the disk (the image is not saved yet, I want to display its size on the screen before it is saved.)

Comment: I see. I don't know how to get back the size for imageBuffer in above example. But the docu for `CGBitmapContextCreate` tells a bit how large the buffer should be (it's calculated from the width/height/color map).

Comment: I guess your image is of type NSImage. If so, you can use NSImage.representation.bitsPerSample multiplied with the size (width*height).